# how to choose the delta value in EM clustering in ELKI

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, gaussian, elki

What should we choose the value of delta in EM clustering?

It gives different values of the measures for different values of delta.

Comment: Please provide a bit more context.  What have you already tried?  Code samples are usually very helpful to answering questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delta parameter in EM is necessary to detect convergence. Since EM uses soft assignments internally, it will continue updating the values to arbitrary digits (technically, it will eventually run out of precision, and stop). As long as you choose a small enough value, you should be fine.

However, EM is initialized *randomly*. You have different options for initialization, but it is a **best practise** to start with a randomized initialization. Running EM multiple times and keeping only the best result is a feasible way to reduce the chance of finding a *local optimum* only.

Therefore, it is not at all surprising you get different results. In fact, you should be seeing different results with the *same* delta, too...

See also: [Wikipedia EM clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm#Termination)